# The best way to create signed certificate request and verify certificate from UEFI

Tags: openssl, bios, uefi, edk2

I'm trying to create signed certificate request from C code in UEFI (I use edk2).

I know how to do it using openssl in Linux C code. I know there is *CryptoPkg* in edk2.
But I didn't find functions to create request and check certificate.

Is there any way to create `X509_REQ` and check `X509` certificate using *CryptoPkg*? And how can I do it?

In the case if I can't do it: How can I create create request and check certificate? What is the best way to create my own openssl wrapper?

Comment: In my `ListCerts.efi` utility,  I parse and display portions of firmware X509 certificates.  The source code for this utility is available at https://github.com/fpmurphy/UEFI-Utilities-2019/tree/master/MyApps/ListCerts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. I figured out that the best way for me is create my own wrapper in *CryptoPkg*.
So I created library in `CryptoPkg\Library\MyCryptLib` according to `CryptoPkg\Library\BaseCryptLib`, copy enviroment header and library paths to link.

So I've got openssl wrapper that I can expand and use